# Running make run 2 times on a makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, executable

I'm running a two executalble makefile, and I got this problem:
Everytime I do a make run (heuristica or otimo) it runs the otimo and then runs the exe I've said to run (if I choose otimo then it runs 2 times).
I'm using Linux (Kubuntu 12.10).
I want to use make run separate, and if I choose to run one, I don't want to run the other or anything like that. Can someone help me on that?
Makelfile code:

```
# Lista dos objetos:
OBJS = main.o grafo.o circulo.o arquivos.o Lista.o 

# Nome dos executáveis:
MAIN1 = tp2h 
MAIN2 = tp2o

# Argumentos para execução dos programas:
ARGS  = input.txt output.txt
ARGS2 = input.txt output.txt

# Especifica o compilador:
CC = gcc

# Especifica as opções do compilador:
CFLAGS = -Wall -pg -g3

# Compilação dos programas:
all: $(MAIN1) $(MAIN2)

$(MAIN1): $(OBJS)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -lm -o $(MAIN1)
$(MAIN2): $(OBJS)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -lm -o $(MAIN2)
%.o: %.c %.h
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c 

# Execução dos programas:

run heuristica:
    ./$(MAIN1) $(ARGS)
run otimo:
    ./$(MAIN2) $(ARGS2)

# Remoção dos objetos pré-compilados:
clean: 
    rm *.o
```

Thanks for any help on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that these are multiple word "targets" that you are using. Makefile targets should be a single word. To correct you can either take the "run" out of the target. Or you can use an underscore instead of a space.

Example 1:

```
# Execução dos programas:

heuristica:
    ./$(MAIN1) $(ARGS)
otimo:
    ./$(MAIN2) $(ARGS2)
```

Example 2:

```
# Execução dos programas:

run_heuristica:
    ./$(MAIN1) $(ARGS)
run_otimo:
    ./$(MAIN2) $(ARGS2)
```